# rails accepts_nested_attributes_for - Error: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'offers.' in 'where clause'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-attributes

Code is:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :offer, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :offer
  ...
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :client
  ...
end


<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @client], :html=>  {:multipart => true } do |f| %>
..some input fields
<%= f.simple_fields_for :offer, @client.new_record? ? Offer.new : ""  do |o| %>
..some input fields
```

This works for new entries, but does not update.

> Error: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'offers.' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM `offers` WHERE `offers`.`` = 718

When I change the client model to:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :offer, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:name].blank?}
```

The error message is gone,it updates the client table but not the offer table.

This is working:

```
  has_one :offer, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :offer, allow_destroy: true

  belongs_to :client

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :offer, @client.new_record? ? Offer.new : @client.offer  do |o| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

First it seems logical that it doesn't work for update, as when you're doing :

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :offer, @client.new_record? ? Offer.new : ""  do |o| %>
```

the simple fields for will try to create fields for "", whereas it should be using the offer object.
You could fix that with (there might be a better way to do this, this is just one solution, not THE solution)

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :offer, @client.offer.new_record? ? Offer.new : @client.offer  do |o| %>
```

EDIT : I think it would be better to only build the offer if it doesn't exist, so here what it would look like :

```
<% @client.build_offer if @client.offer.new_record? %>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :offer do |o| %>
```